# Get the available space of Dropbox using Linux command line

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, dropbox

I'm using CentOS.  Is there a way to get the unused space in my Dropbox account using the command line?

Comment: You would have thought the [Official Dropbox Command Line Interface (CLI)](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli) would have an option to query the free space but unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Dropbox API to get your current usage.  Download the [Python SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/python) (and make sure you have Python installed).  In the examples folder of the SDK there is a `cli_client.py`.  Edit that file with your developer keys and then use the "account_info" command to see your usage.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be an official solution for this. You can however use `du` to find out the size of your Dropbox folder and calculate how much space you have left from that.

Some example scripts doing a similar thing can be found [on this page](http://conky.pitstop.free.fr/wiki/index.php5?title=Dropbox_percentage_used_%28en%29). Just calculate the difference instead of the percentage.

I would use `du -cLl $HOME/Dropbox` instead of `du -c $HOME/Dropbox`. This way symbolic links and hardlinks are counted correctly.

Also note that this solution only works if you sync your complete Dropbox on the PC in question. If you use *selective sync*, you must approximate the space used by folders not present on this system. This makes the system unreliable.
As a workaround you could have a cronjob that writes the sizes of other folders into a file in your dropbox and use this file for your calculations.